# Pandas editing dataframe within function without returning dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, in-place

### I'm writing some code to edit a dataframe within the scope of a function, where I return a separately edited variable, a list.

---

From my understanding of scope, if a variable is edited within a function but not assigned over, then that value will not be persisted into the outer scope. Like this:

```
def var_and_list_function(var, my_list):
    var = var + 1
    print(var)
    my_list.append(50)
    return my_list
var = 1

my_list = var_and_list_function(var, my_list) # local value is 2
2
var # but outside of the function it is still 1
1
```

---

So, that's how I think it should work with Pandas, but that's not what I've found. I have to make a copy within the function in order to not edit the original, even when not returned as above.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1])
print(dataframe)
   0
0  1
1  1
2  1

my_list = [18,15,16]
def dataframe_and_list_function(dataframe, my_list):
    dataframe[0] = dataframe[0].apply(lambda x: x+1)
    print('Your dataframe inside the function is:')
    print(dataframe)
    my_list.append(4)
    return my_list

my_list = dataframe_and_list_function(dataframe, my_list)
Your dataframe inside the function is:
   0
0  2
1  2
2  2


dataframe # but the dataframe itself has been edited without being returned
   0
0  2
1  2
2  2
```

Does this question make sense?

---

I would expect the dataframe to **not** be edited outside of the scope of the function being called, but here we see the dataframe is edited within a local scope and written over in the outer scope.

Am I running into a known issue with Pandas? Or rather, is this not an issue at all, simply an inconsistency in implementation from Python to Pandas? The latter is my supposition, but then again I am unsure, which is why I am asking!

Comment: This seems to be a case of shallow vs deep copy in python - look into df.copy

Comment: This is an expected behavior in Python. Pandas dataframes are mutable objects; you might think about them as passed by reference. Thus, when you change the referenced object you actually change the original dataframe. The same logic applies to lists, dictionaries and other mutable types. However, for immutable types (int, str, bool) it will be what you expect

Comment: That's super helpful. Thanks @Marat!

Answer (score 0):

Marat responded in the comments and answered this question as soon as it was posted.

> This is an expected behavior in Python. Pandas dataframes are mutable objects; you might think about them as passed by reference. Thus, when you change the referenced object you actually change the original dataframe. The same logic applies to lists, dictionaries and other mutable types. However, for immutable types (int, str, bool) it will be what you expect